# In python tk inter module, I want to print multiple results

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
import random as rd

def lottery_number():
    num = int(number.get())
    for i in range(num):
        lotto_list = list(range(1,46))   #from 1 to 45
        rd.shuffle(lotto_list) #shuffle
        lotto_list1 = lotto_list[:6]  
        lotto_list1.sort() #sorting 
        answer = '{}  Auto'.format(i), lotto_list1
    result.config(text=answer)

from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
label = Label(window, text = 'press lottery game number.')
label.pack()

number =Entry(window, width = 30)
number.pack()

btn = Button(window, text = 'Click', fg = 'blue', command = lottery_number)
btn.pack()

result = Label(window, text = 'Result')
result.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

the result is just one.  for example,  {1} Auto 3, 5, 9, 30 ,33

I want print multiple results like below

```
                          {1} Auto 3, 5, 9, 30 ,33
                          {2} Auto 4, 6, 9, 23 ,44
                          {3} Auto 1, 7, 9, 20 ,26
```

thanks .

Actually, I want print like this below

```
                      {A} Auto 3, 5, 9, 30 ,33
                      {B} Auto 4, 6, 9, 23 ,44
                      {C} Auto 1, 7, 9, 20 ,26
```

Comment: In your loop, you overwrite `answer` on each iteration.

Comment: How can I overwrite answer?